# Extract the audio data from RTP packets

Tags: audio, rtp, packets, payload

I have RTP packets and I use the pcap.net Packet Object.
I need to get the actual audio data from the packet, without the RTP header - just the payload.

Language: C#

thnaks,
Ofek

Answer (score 0):

RTP header length is 12 bytes usually. Using pcap.net you can create an object of udp.

```
UdpDatagram udp = null;
```

Then use

```
udp.Payload.ToHexadecimal();
```

So you will get full RTP . In that above hex string remove first 12 byte, that will be the rtp data(ex :voice).